# Unable to get the updated value for dataset in div using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on some java script changes for updating the div data attribute values. Below is the detailed explanation.

I have a div with some data attributes and initially when the page loads they are set to some default values.

```
<div class="offer_option" id="offerView" data-term="24" data-rc="54.99">
   <a href="#" class="customize_offer" id="customize">Select</a>
</div>
```

Through an Ajax call i am trying to update the "data-rc" value as below.

```
document.getElementById("offerView").dataset.rc = 100.00;
```

or

```
$("#offerView").data('rc', 100.00);
```

When i click the "select" link the below code will execute

```
$('.customize_offer').unbind('click').click(function() {
    selectOffer($(this));
});
```

Below is the "selectOffer" function

```
function selectOffer(selectButton) {
   var offerOption = selectButton.parents('.offer_option');
   var offerDetails = offerOption.data();
   console.log( offerDetails );
}
```

The problem is the dataset does not showing the updated value for data-rc in the "offerDetails" variable, instead it is showing an empty value. I have tried with some j query options and java script options but i am not able to get the updated values in the "offerDetails" variable. Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks,
Nagendra

Comment: Try replacing `parents` with `closest`

Comment: @Nagendra: try to log : console.log(offerOption ); if it return an object or undefined

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("#offerView").attr('data-rc', 100.00);
```

Why it happens?

`jQuery .data()` is initially populated with values from the data-attributes by using a special cache object inside jQuery to store data .It doesn't change the attribute in the DOM. To change the attribute, you have to use `attr()`

Comment: But the OP *is* using `data()` to get the values, so the attribute shouldn't matter ?

Comment: But he states `Through an Ajax call i am trying to update the "data-rc" value `

Comment: @magesh Kumaar. That code should be written like this: .attr("data-rc", 100.00)

Comment: @MageshKumaar - it's unclear to me what the OP means by *"Through an Ajax call..."* but the code sets data with `data()` and tries to get that data back with `data()`, which should work fine.

Comment: @NachoDawg - single or double quotes makes no difference.

Comment: @adeneo I assumed he's trying to modify the data-attribute. Let me wait for the OP to clear this out

Comment: @adeneo he has corrected the issue, which was that he wrote: .attr("rc", 100), instead of .attr("data-rc", 100)

Comment: @NachoDawg - oh okay, checked the edits now, didn't see the first version so it looked like the only difference in your comment was the quotes.